# how to delete rows that contain a word from a list in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, list-comprehension

As stated in the title I have a pandas data frame with string sentences in the column "title". I know want to filter all rows, where the title column contains one of the words specified in the list "keywords".

keywords = ["Simon", "Mustermann"]

df =

| Title | Bla |
| --- | --- |
| Simon is a python beginner | ... |
| Second balaola | ... |
| Simon | ... |

Since "Simon" is found in rows with index 0 and 2, they should be retained.

My code atm is the following:
`new_df = df[df["title"].isin(keywords)]`
However, it only contains the third row but not the first one. How can I fix this? Thanks a lot for your support and time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet should work for you

```
keywords = ["Simon", "Mustermann"]

# filter rows where column title contains one of the keywords
df_filtered = df[df["title"].str.contains("|".join(keywords))]
```

Comment: Thanks cnemri it worked! What if I have a second column "text" and I want to retain all rows that contain one of the words specified in the "keywords" list in at least one column ("title" or "text")?

Comment: df_filtered = df.loc[df["Title"].str.contains("|".join(keywords)) | df["Text"].str.contains("|".join(keywords))]